# Exception in application start method in javafx project

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create a JavaFX program, and every time I try to run my code I am getting an exception - I'm not entirely sure what it means though...

My code:

FXML Document

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="49.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="337.0" prefWidth="503.0">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="user" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="77.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="237.0" promptText="Username" />
            <JFXPasswordField fx:id="pass" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="237.0" promptText="Password" />
            <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="handleButtonAction" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="112.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c50ba;" text="Login" textFill="#d1d4dd">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Andalus" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <ImageView fitHeight="248.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="289.0" layoutY="37.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Admin.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentcotroller

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package projetoracle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;


/**
 *
 * @author HP
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

   @FXML
    private JFXTextField user;

    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField pass;

    @FXML
    private Button login;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String username = user.getText();
        String password = pass.getText();
        if (username.equals("System")&&password.equals("Manager"))
        {
        Connection con =connexion.getConnection();
        }
        else 
        System.out.println("erreur");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Stack Trace

```
Executing C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projetoracle\dist\run1189234243\projetoracle.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='handleButtonAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/C:/Users/HP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/projetoracle/dist/run1189234243/projetoracle.jar!/projetoracle/FXMLDocument.fxml:22

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at projetoracle.Projetoracle.start(Projetoracle.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application projetoracle.Projetoracle
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projetoracle\dist\run1189234243
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

I try all the solutions given about this topic but i keep on getting the same error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need

```xml
    <Button fx:id="login" ... onAction="#handleButtonAction" ... >
```

(note the `#` before the method name), and

2. You appear not to have specified the controller class with `fx:controller="..."` in the root element of the FXML. (Maybe you are setting the controller directly in code - you didn't show where you load the FXML - in which case you will not need this.)

Comment: when i put # before the methode name , netbeans notice an error about the controller  : the controller is not defined in root component ! please help me ti fix it  ..

Comment: i read it but i can't defined the controller can you please complete this fx:controller="..."

Comment: I'm just referring to the usual way of specifying the controller. See any basic documentation on FXML, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers/5125/example-fxml#t=201704111703360850885 or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the code fragments below;

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction() {
```

means remove the parameter and

```
<Button fx:id="login" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="112.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c50ba;" text="Login" textFill="#d1d4dd">
```

and add a # before the method name.

Comment: Why remove the method parameter?

Comment: It seems to be useless, actually not important.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the code below;

```
@FXML
public void handleButtonAction() {}
```

and you have to specify your controller in the fxml file.

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.sample.FXMLDocumentController ">
```

**replace com.sample.FXMLDocumentController**  with your package name.

```
<Button fx:id="login" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="112.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c50ba;" text="Login" textFill="#d1d4dd">
```